# Uploading file on server apache via php

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, debian

I'm trying to download a file from my website to my server but can't find why or where I'm doing that wrong.

Here my php code :

```
    $fn = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    if (is_writable('.')) { 
        echo "Writable<BR>";
    } else {
        echo "Not writable<BR>";
    }
    $upfile = './'.basename($fn);
    echo $upfile.'<BR>';
    shell_exec("echo 'baaaaah' > test.baaaah");
    $f = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    echo $f.'<BR>';
    if (is_uploaded_file($f)) { echo "uploaded<BR>"; } else { echo "not uploaded<BR>";} 
    $com = "test - f ".$f." && echo 'F' || echo 'N'";
    echo $com.'<BR>';
    echo shell_exec($com).'<BR>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($f,$uploadfile)) {
        echo "File transfer OK<BR>";
    } else {
        echo "File transfer NOK<BR>";
    }
    print_r($_FILES);
```

And here the website output :

```
Writable
./flag.jpg
/tmp/phpyKvhEz
uploaded
test - f /tmp/phpyKvhEz && echo 'F' || echo 'N'
N 
File transfer NOK
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => flag.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpyKvhEz [error] => 0 [size] => 1660 ) )
```

So first thing I check if my folder is writable (it's not intended to be '.' but I moved to here because the folder I want wasn't working either (same behavior as '.' through...)) => check

Then I try to shell_exec a file here juste to be sure => check, file is on server

Then I check if the temp file is created on the server :
- check, anyway is_uploaded thinks the file is here
- not check, but a test on the temp file doesn't work (and since the file is not supposed to be removed before the end of the script it should see the file here imho ?)

Then I try to make the move_uploaded_file => not check

And I print the $_FILES who shows nothing suspicious (error = 0, file names matches what I see before).

I can't figure what goes wrong nor where a mistake can come from ><

Comment: You don't seem to define the destination file name `$uploadfile` anywhere. You probably want `$upfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$uploadfile is undefined in your code. Change it or set it to '.' and it should work.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... I changed it to $upfile and I worked indeed